# Groovy dynamic methods, from Java (or any other JVM language)... how?

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, groovy, gradle-plugin

I'm writing a Gradle plugin using Kotlin.

This plugin will, however, be used using the groovy dsl.

One of the things I want to achieve is to have a block that works similar to the `dependencies` block. That block somehow translates statements like:
`testImplementation "some:library:1"` to `add("testImplementation","some:library:1")`.

so I assume `testImplementation`, `implementation`, `api` and others, are just methods that exist dynamically in the `dependencies` block delegate.

How can I achieve a similar behavior when writing plugins using either Java or Kotlin?

Comment: I would be somewhat surprised if this were possible.

Comment: I guess you should be able to achive this by creating some kind of a Groovy wrapper around your plugin. But not with Kotlin alone.